# Why isn't the index being set properly for following cloned array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone an array, reset the index (0, 1, 3 ...) and save this array in a `buildingsPayload` variable:

```
console.log('1:', this.buildings)

const buildingsPayload = this.buildings.map((building, index) => {
  return Object.assign({ index: index }, building)
})

console.log('2:', buildingsPayload)
```

The index in `console.log('1')` is:

```
[
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 1 }
]
```

And the index in `console.log('2')` is also:

```
[
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 1 }
]
```

How to modify this code so `buildingsPayload` ends up like:

```
[
  { index: 0 },
  { index: 1 },
  { index: 2 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later objects’ keys override those of earlier objects in `Object.assign`, so you need to specify `{ index: index }` last:

```
const buildingsPayload = this.buildings.map((building, index) =>
  Object.assign({}, building, { index: index }))
```